# Placeholder not loading in WP8 WebBrowser?

Tags: windows-phone

I'm developing Windows Phone 8 Application, In my application, I'm loading a page which has text box with placeholders in it, the problem is that when i load the page, the values in the placeholder appear at the top of the text box.
What can I do to make it appear as a placeholder

Comment: Add your code snippet so people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking of a watermarked implementation of the `TextBox` control. You can either manually edit the template or just use an existing implementation (details [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arun/archive/2010/03/29/watermarked-text-box-for-windows-phone.aspx)).

If it is somehow related to the `WebBrowser` control, edit your answer to include that detail.